# LibGDX - Scaling Isometric Tiled Map to screen size. Larger screen larger map

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to LibGDX so I'm stil trying to get the gist of it. I rendered an Isometric map onto the screen and finally after almost 2 days I managed to center it on the screen. However it remains the same size no matter how large the screen is. here's what I mean:

[800x600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqg71.png)

[1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwDoT.png)

What I want it to do is to scale the map up depending on how large the screen is. Here's the code:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private IsometricTiledMapRenderer isometricRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    public void createUI() {
        // Load map from tiled .tmx file.
        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("arena1/arena1.tmx");

        // Setup isometric renderer and camera.
        isometricRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map);
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        createUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        isometricRenderer.setView(camera);
        isometricRenderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width * 2;
        camera.viewportHeight = height * 2;
        camera.position.set(768, 0, 0);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        isometricRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with different screen sizes libGDX has [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports). They keep 
ratio of all drawing on a screen the same on different screens.

For example [FitViewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/FitViewport.java) it will always maintain the aspect ratio of the virtual screen size, while scaling it as much as possible to fit the screen.

```
  public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    private TiledMap map;
    private IsometricTiledMapRenderer isometricRenderer;
    private FitViewport viewport;

    public void createUI() {
        // Load map from tiled .tmx file.
        map = new TmxMapLoader().load("arena1/arena1.tmx");

        // Setup isometric renderer and camera.
        isometricRenderer = new IsometricTiledMapRenderer(map);

        int width = 800; // Can change to other
        int height = 480;
        viewport = new FitViewport(width, height, new OrthographicCamera(width, height));

        viewport.camera.position.set(768, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        isometricRenderer.setView(viewport.camera);
        isometricRenderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Had to cast it to OrthographicCamera like this:

    isometricRenderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) 
    fitViewport.getCamera());

and it worked perfectly, thanks!